# Using HttpGet to execute command in a Webserver

Tags: java, http-get

Hey All, I'm doing a project on remotely controlling my RC car with an installed adruino board and wifly shied. The wifly shied has its own webserver set up and the configurations of moving up, down, left and right is set. However, I have problems in my android app regarding how to access the webserver when I click my move forward button. Below is the sample code and I'm stuck from there.

```
public class GetUrl extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        View forward_Button = findViewById(R.id.forwardButton);
        forward_Button.setOnClickListener(this);
}
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.forwardButton:
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://192.168.1.3/?LED=Fowd");
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);

            break;
```

Comment: Please elaborate on "I'm stuck."  What problems are you having?  You can remove the first (redundant) `HttpResponse response;` line.  Other than that, it looks pretty good.

Comment: Sorry. Edited the redundant HttpResponse. In my eclipse, it shows error at the line "HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);" which is "unhandled exception type type CLientProtocol Exception"

Answer (score 0):

JAVA 101 : httpclient.execute(httpget); throws an exception that you have to catch :

```
try {
  httpclient.execute(httpget);
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
  e.printStackStrace();
}
```